# How to set up Slave Database configuration in vBulletin?

Tags: vbulletin

How to set up Slave Database configuration in vBulletin ? I set up like this:

$config['Database']['dbtype'] = 'mysql';

$config['Database']['dbname'] = 'xyz';

$config['Database']['tableprefix'] = 'vbulletin1_';

$config['Database']['technicalemail'] = 'xyz@abc.com';

$config['Database']['force_sql_mode'] = false;

$config['MasterServer']['servername'] = 'xyz';

$config['MasterServer']['port'] = 3306;

$config['MasterServer']['username'] = 'x';

$config['MasterServer']['password'] = 'xxxx';

$config['MasterServer']['usepconnect'] = 0;

$config['SlaveServer']['servername'] = 'abc';

$config['SlaveServer']['port'] = 3306;

$config['SlaveServer']['username'] = 'a';

$config['SlaveServer']['password'] = 'xxxx';

$config['SlaveServer']['usepconnect'] = 0;

Answer (score 0):

This is depends from your slave DB credentials only. And "Slave DB" means that you have replicated DB on your host (vBulletin can't make this, it should be done automatically by your web server). So, if you have not a replicated DB, you should not setup Slave DB.

A Master-Slave setup is for performance. You send write queries to the master server, and most read queries to the slave server. It helps improve performance because write queries lock tables/rows depending on the database table type, and reads do not.
[vBulletin forum](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-legacy-versions-products/legacy-vbulletin-versions/vbulletin-3-5-how-do-i-questions-and-troubleshooting/155225-slave-database-configuration)